# Change spinner indicator drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

In 4.x devices, the drawable which indicates that this is a spinner and should be clicked is barely visible; it is using spinner_ab_default_holo_light.9.png. How can I make it use spinner_ab_default_holo_dark.9.png, or any other drawable of my choice?

[image: Can't see spinner indicator]

The spinner is in a dialog. The app uses ActionbarSherlock 4.3.1 for Android 2.2.3 upwards compatibility. The app implements [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to create a Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar theme. I am using a Values and a Values-v14 to manage the styles. This dialog attaches a specific style:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FibroDialog))
```

which, in Values-v14, has a parent theme to make sure the dialog background is dark:

```
<style name="FibroDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">

</style>
```

Things I have tried:

In the theme generated by Android Action Bar Style Generator I added

```
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerItemStyle</item>
```

and then added

```
<style name="MySpinnerItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_fibromapp</item>
</style>
```

which resulted in the drawable I actually want becoming the background of the item, not the spinner.

[image]

In the xml for the spinner, I tried

```
android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/spinner_ab_default_fibromapp"
```

which gives the same result as above, and

```
android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_ab_default_fibromapp"
```

which replaces the background of each spinner item with the drawable.

As a last resort, I made my own spinner_ab_default_holo_dark and spinner_ab_default_holo_light 9-patches; and they didn't show up at all.

How *can* I access that spinner drawable and change it to whatever graphic I want?

Answer (score 1):

Although i'm new at this, i've also spent far too many hours looking for a similar answer. It seems the only solution is to create a style which is an exact copy of the system's spinner style and edit that which you which to change. It's troublesome, boring and not really practical, but if it must be done, it must be done... Due to time constraints, I ended up changing my layout a bit so that the standard spinner wouldn't look too bad.